# Get value from javascript onclick in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making an page with every video I upload to the database.

They are filtered by date and ordered by date. There is an onclick on every video with JavaScript. With all the value's it has to show on the website.

But when I click on the video it has to filter all the video´s with the tags they have. The only thing it does now, it shows the right tag with the video but not the right tag when I want to filter it. Then it gives me the tag from the video that is posted first.

How do I get the right tag value when there clicked on? when I want to filter the tags?

```html
<?php

$query = $connectie->prepare("SELECT v.VideoID,v.Titel,v.Link,v.Omschrijving,o.Bestandspath, o.Bestandsnaam,o.Onderwerp,t.Naam, DATE_FORMAT(`postDate`,\"%e-%m-%Y %H:%i\")as tijd FROM video v join opdracht o on v.OpdrachtID = o.OpdrachtID JOIN videotag vt on v.VideoID = vt.VideoID
JOIN tag t on vt.TagID = t.TagID order by `postDate` ");
$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $link = $row['Link'];
    $newLink = str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $link);
    $data = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=' . $link);
    // echo $newLink;
    $json = json_decode($data);
    $thumbnail = $json->thumbnail_url;
    $title = $json->title;
    $onderwerp = $row['Onderwerp'];
    $omschrijving = $row['Omschrijving'];
    $filePath = $row['Bestandspath'];
    $bestandsnaam = $row['Bestandsnaam'];
    $videoid = $row['VideoID'];
    $tagName = $row['Naam'];
    echo 'tagname',$tagName;

    echo
    '
        <div class="scrollbar">
            <a id="videoList" name="video" href="#" onclick="getLink(\'' . htmlentities($newLink) . '\',\'' . htmlentities($title) . '\',\'' . htmlentities($onderwerp) . '\',\''.htmlentities($tagName) . '\',\'' . htmlentities($omschrijving) . '\',\'' . htmlentities($bestandsnaam) . '\',\'' . htmlentities($filePath) . '\')">
                <img src="' .htmlentities($thumbnail) . '" width="235"/>
                <p id="titelText"><b>' . htmlentities($title) . '</b></p>
            </a>
        </div>

        <script>
            function getLink(link,titel,onderwerp,tagNaam,omschrijving,bestandsnaam,bestandspath){
                document.getElementById("videoFrame").src = link;
                document.getElementById("videoFrame").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("overzicht").style.width = "275px";
                document.getElementById("panelInfo").style.display = "block";


                document.getElementById("titelVideo").innerHTML = "<b>Titel</b>:"+titel+"<br>";
                document.getElementById("onderwerp").innerHTML = "<b>Onderwerp</b>:"+onderwerp+"<br>";
                document.getElementById("tagnaam").innerHTML =  "<b>Tag</b>:" + tagNaam + "<br>";
                document.getElementById("omschrijving").innerHTML = "<b>Omschrijving</b>:"+omschrijving;

                document.getElementById("bestand").download = bestandsnaam;
                document.getElementById("bestand").href = bestandspath;
            }
        </script>';

}
```

Comment: You can't do this, like this.. PHP is server side and JS is clientside.

Comment: Is there another why to do this?

Comment: It looks like you're adding a `<script>` element under EVERY `<div class="scrollbar">` element? Is your while-loop above adding multiple sets of scrollbars / script tags?

Comment: @MissesA - Do you want the tag value to be captured server side or clientside? Sorry just struggling to understand what needs to happen. Also take your <script> out of the while loop and add after the loop, this will cause wierdness, and looking again, it's likely this is the problem.

Comment: I want it to captures server-side. I am sorry if it is not clear. The tags need to be captured by the server. Then it has to find the same tags from the other videos and show them. That should theoretically  happen when the video is clicked to show.

Comment: I would recommend learning Node.js: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-7RQ46RgxU&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gcy9lrvMJ75z9maRw4byYp